# How to declare a pointer within a class definition to the class being defined?

Tags: c++

I am new to C++, and I am learning classes now. I have found this class and wondering how works object created as a pointer in its own class. Can you guys explain it please? Where and how can it be used?

```
class Car {
public:
    int weight;
    const char* model;
    Car* other;
};
```

Comment: Please make sure to read how to write good questions.   Stack overflow isn't here to teach people how to program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class Car {
public:
    // ...
    Car* other;
};
```

At the moment of declaring the data member `other`, the `Car` class is actually an *incomplete type* (i.e., it is not completely defined). As a result, the compiler doesn't know the size of a `Car` object yet. However, since this data member `other` is **a pointer to a `Car` object** rather than a `Car` object, the compiler does know the size of `other`.

Comment: Future readers: as an intellectual exercise, think on what the effect of changing the rules to allow `Car` to directly contain `Car` members would have on the size of the resulting object.

Comment: @user4581301 you cant change rules of logic :P

Answer (score 4):

This can be used for example in a linked-list  where a Node of the list has to also hold a reference to the next Node in the list.

```
class Node
{
public:
    int value;
    Node* next;
};

class LinkedList
{
public:
    Node head;
}
```

The reason why the `next` Node is a pointer here is that the class is not yet fully defined and thus the compiler doesn't know its size. But since pointers have always a fixed size, we can store a `Node*` as a class member just fine.

Comment: What do you mean by "class is not fully defined"?

Comment: @Nerfi Well, the class definition has not ended, since the line declaring `next` is part of it.